# Como fazer include de classe em pesquisa no Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Desenvolvi um sistema Code First em Asp.Net MVC
Neste desenvolvimento criei um relacionamento **muito para muito** e quero fazer uma pesquisa que inclua este relacionamentos em uma pesquisa, abaixo descrevo melhor em código o que desenvolvi

Tenho as seguinte classes.
**Empresa**, **Categorias** e a classe de relacionamento **EmpresaCategorias**.

**Classe Empresa**

```
public class Empresa
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public string Telefone { get; set; }

    public ICollection<EmpresaCategoria> CategoriaEmpresa { get; set; }
}
```

**Classe Categoria**

```
public class Categoria
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public ICollection<EmpresaCategoria> CategoriaEmpresa { get; set; }
}
```

**Classe de Relacionamento NxN**

```
public class EmpresaCategoria
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Categoria")]
    public int CategoriaId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Empresa")]
    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }

    public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
    public virtual Empresa Empresa { get; set; }
}
```

No Controller tenho uma pesquisa que funciona, mas ela pesquisa somente Empresa, quero também incluir a Categoria

```
    public ActionResult Resultado(string pesquisaEmpresaOuCategoria)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pesquisaEmpresaOuCategoria))
        {
            return Redirect("Index");
        }

        /*
         *Quero Incluir a categoria nesta pesquisa
         *include
         */

        return View(db.Empresa.Where(x => x.Nome.Contains(pesquisaEmpresaOuCategoria)).ToList());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [.Any()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) para isso.

```
public ActionResult Resultado(string pesquisaEmpresaOuCategoria)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pesquisaEmpresaOuCategoria))
    {
        return Redirect("Index");
    }

    /*
     *Quero Incluir a categoria nesta pesquisa
     *include
     */

    return View(db.Empresa.Where(x => x.Nome.Contains(pesquisaEmpresaOuCategoria) || x.CategoriaEmpresa.Any(c => c.Categoria.Nome.Contains(pesquisaEmpresaOuCategoria))).ToList());
}
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dJZIz2)

Outra forma também é você buscar o valor na classe de relacionamento, desta forma:

```
return View(db.EmpresaCategoria.Where(x => x.Empresa.Nome.Contains(pesquisaEmpresaOuCategoria) || x.Categoria.Nome.Contains(pesquisaEmpresaOuCategoria)).ToList());
```

Caso queira retornar somente as empresas, você pode utilizar o `.Select()` para retornar somente a empresa.

Comment: Randrade sua resposta funcionou, gostaria que me respondesse novamente, pois acrescentei novas dívidas neste tópico.

Comment: @cyberlacs Como você tem outra pergunta, o ideal é abrir uma nova pergunta pergunta com a sua nova dúvida. Desta forma mantemos o histórico e podemos ajudar mais pessoas. Você pode linkar essa com a nova para ser mais fácil de entender.
Aproveitando, se realmente abrir uma nova pergunta, explique um pouco mais o que deseja, pois eu não consegui entender direito a sua edição. 
Qualquer dúvida é só avisar.

Comment: atendendo ao seu comunicado fiz outra pergunta esta neste link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/249251/campo-textbox-pesquisa-empresa-e-categoria-e-campo-dropdownlist-cidades-pesquisa